# Why is Twitter not accepting my short url that does not contain .co?

Tags: twitter

Why is Twitter not accepting my short url that does not contain .co? the url in question is vote4thame.uk, It works in search engines but doesn't display as a link on Twitter.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to a specific tweet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as the URL is primarily a redirect URL, you may wish to just post the final link it directs to as it will be shortened by the t.co shortener.

Also I was able to post a .uk url just fine, so it isn't directly correlated to just .uk domains.

Example URL I used: www.nominet.uk

I was also able to post the URL you provided just fine as well, so perhaps Twitter was rejecting your tweet as spam?

Sources:
https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623
https://support.twitter.com/articles/18311